# with the api bot telegram

Tags: python, telegram

Please help me fix this bug in my Python code.

> Error type: Update tool.**init**() got an unexpected argument of the keyword 'token'

Code:

```
# Telegram Bot API
from telegram.text import Updater

updater = Updater(token='my bot token', context_user=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
```

I've tried different versions of the code, I can't figure out what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

- The `Updater` class should be imported from `telegram.ext`, not `text`
- For older `python-bot-api` versions, remove the `token=` part
- Looking at the `Updater()` [source code](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/ext/_updater.py), there is no option called `context_user`, so remove that too

---

```py
from telegram.ext import Updater

updater = Updater('my bot token')
```

Comment: now it gives out such an error, can you tell me what it's connected with? TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_user'

Comment: That is a non valid option, please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

telegram-bot==3.2.0 package it working fine and passing token as following

```
from telegram import Updater
updater = Updater(token='token')
```